# How do you construct a bivariate normal pdf (or 2D Gaussian) using measure theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Suppose I have an experiment $\mathcal{E}$ and a corresponding probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ where:

- $\Omega$ is the set of possible outcomes
- $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma-algebra on it
- $\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{F}\to [0,1]$ is a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

Now suppose there are two additional measurable spaces $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X}) = (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $(\mathsf{Y}, \mathcal{Y})=(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ and we define two random variables
$$
X: \Omega \to \mathsf{X} \\
Y: \Omega \to \mathsf{Y}
$$
with probability distributions defined as push-forward measures
$$
\pi_X := X_*\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{X} \to [0, 1] \\
\pi_Y := Y_*\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{Y} \to [0, 1]
$$
which we assume to satisfy $\pi_X \ll \lambda$ and $\pi_Y \ll \lambda$ where $\lambda$ is the $1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Then their density functions are the Random-Nykodym derivatives
$$
f_X := \frac{d \pi_X}{d\lambda}:X \to [0, +\infty) \\
f_Y := \frac{d \pi_Y}{d\lambda}:Y \to [0, +\infty).
$$
Finally, we assume that their densities have the form of two standard normal distributions
$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \\
f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)
$$
so that their CDFs become
$$
\begin{align*}
F_X(x)
&:= \pi_X((-\infty, x]) = \int_{(-\infty, x]} d\pi_X = \int_{(-\infty, x]} f_X d\lambda = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{(-\infty, x]} \exp\left(- \frac{t^2}{2}\right) dt \\
F_Y(y)
&:= \pi_Y((-\infty, y]) = \int_{(-\infty, y]} d\pi_Y = \int_{(-\infty, y]} f_Y d\lambda = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{(-\infty, y]} \exp\left(- \frac{t^2}{2}\right) dt
\end{align*}
$$
But then I am not sure about how to construct a general bivariate normal distribution with arbitrary mean and covariance matrix.

## Following the Answer by Woolier

We collect together the two random variables into a $2D$ random vector
$$
(X, Y): \Omega \times \Omega \to \mathsf{X}\times \mathsf{Y}
$$
and define its probability distribution as
$$
\pi_{X\times Y} := \pi_X \times \pi_Y: \mathcal{X} \otimes \mathcal{Y} \to [0, 1]
$$
The probability density function is then given by the product
$$
f_{X\times Y} = \frac{d \pi_X}{d \lambda} \times \frac{d \pi_Y}{d \lambda}: X\times Y \to [0, +\infty)
$$
giving the following (we define $\boldsymbol{x} = (x, y)^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 1}$)
$$
\begin{align*}
f_{X\times Y}(x, y) 
&= \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\right]\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{(x^2+y^2)}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (x, y) I \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^\top I \boldsymbol{x}\right)
\end{align*}
$$
Then can then define a new set of random variables
$$
(X', Y') : \Omega\times \Omega \to \mathsf{X}\times\mathsf{Y}
$$
defined as follows. Let $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega$. Then if we let $L$ be the cholesky decomposition (lower-triangular) of a positive-definite matrix $\Sigma = LL^\top$, the values $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$ are mapped to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    X'(\omega) \\
    Y'(\omega)
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
l_{11} & l_{12} \\
l_{21} & l_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
X(\omega) \\
Y(\omega)
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
\mu_1 \\
\mu_2
\end{pmatrix} =:
L\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{\mu}
$$

and therefore we say that $(X', Y')$ follow a $\mathcal{N}(L\boldsymbol{0} + \boldsymbol{\mu}, LIL^\top) = \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{\mu}, \Sigma)$

Comment: What do you mean by 'constructing a distribution'? Any bivariate distribution with joint PDF $f(x,y)$ arises as a Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Radon-Nikodym derivative $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}=f,\qquad\text{i.e.,}\qquad \mu(A)=\int_{A}f\,\mathrm{d}\lambda.$$ So all you have to do is to set $f$ as the bivariate normal density. If your goal is to simulate a bivariate normal using i.i.d. standard normal variables (say, $X$ and $Y$), then you may use the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If $(X,Y)\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma),$ then
$$
A\cdot (X,Y)^T+\mathbf{b}\sim \mathcal{N}(A\mu+\mathbf{b},A\Sigma A^T)
$$
For any matrix $A$ and vector $\mathbf{b}$ of suitable dimensions.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Does it make sense? And can you please tell me if I have not been rigorous at points?

Comment: It looks good to me. One point, though: The order in which you introduce $L$ is a bit weird. I'd write something like "let $LL^T=\Sigma$ be a Choleksy decomposition of $\Sigma$ and define $(Z,W)^T=L(X,Y)^T$" and then, perform the necessary computations.